# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on bool

Tags: php, pdo

Below is my code. I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on
> bool

```
<?php 
    require("connectProduct.php");
```

Get these $_POST from another PHP. Please let me know how can I change?

```
 if (isset($_POST)){
        $brand_name   = trim($_POST['brandname']);
        $product_type = trim($_POST['type']);
        $product_name = trim($_POST['Prodname']);
        $color        = trim($_POST['color']);
        $image        = trim($_POST['image']);
        $id           = (int) $_POST['id'];
        $quantity     = (int) ($_POST['qty']);
        $price        = (float) $_POST['price'];


    try {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO items_table(id, brand_name, product_type,name,price,color,image,quantity) 
            VALUES(:id, :brand_name, :product_type, :product_name, :price, :color, :image, :quantity)';
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

*"Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindParam() on bool"* in below line

```
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":brand_name", $brandname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":product_type", $prodtype);
        $stmt->bindParam(":product_name", $prodname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":price", $price);
        $stmt->bindParam(":color", $color);
        $stmt->bindParam(":image", $image);
        $stmt->bindParam(":quantity", $qty);
        $stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
            header("Location: create.php?status=created");
            exit();
        }
        header("Location: create.php?status=fail_create");
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
} else {
    header("Location: create.php?status=fail_create");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: @Dharman yes im using PHP 7.4

Comment: On PHP 7.4 you need to enable PDO error reporting manually.

Comment: @Dharman what code should i add in

Comment: Read the answer I gave you carefully. It's all there.

Comment: @Dharman i get this error after adding this code 
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

The error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::setAttribute()

Comment: Prepare returned false so there was an error in the sql or with the connection.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO then? Your code is PDO code, but your error states that your `$conn` is an instance of mysqli. Did you read the PHP manual to learn how to open PDO connection properly?

Comment: Im using mysqli . How can i change from PDO to mysqli ?

Comment: @JoshJ i have already check there is no error..

Comment: Why on earth would you want to change the code from PDO to mysqli? Stick with PDO if you have already written PDO code. It's much easier and better than mysqli

Comment: There is definitely an error in SQL if your connection is mysqli. It doesn't support the same features as PDO does. So all of the named placeholders are SQL syntax errors

Comment: @Dharman Im still new with PHP.. Do you have any solution to solve my error please. I really need help. I just want to solve this error and complete my assignment.

Comment: @Dharman so i change my   $sql = 'INSERT INTO items_table(id, brand_name, .... ?

Comment: @Dharman but there is no time for me.. Would you able to help me solve this error? i send you my files

Comment: No. I am not here to help you write your project. Stack Overflow is not a free personal help desk. I have given you materials where you can learn PDO. I can't help you any more. You can't take shortcuts when learning programming. You need to take some time to learn how to do it properly.